# PhoneGap Build for windows phone and other platforms

Tags: android, windows-phone-7, cordova

I have started a project in phonegap for windows phone, and created a login form. Backend I have written some c# code for perform some api methods and check login.

And I have build the phonegap and got output file for all the platform. Whether is it compatible with all other platform than windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For working with cross platform, I have created a web service and called the method of web service with ajax call,
If the webservice hosted in any other domain you should use

```
$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
$.support.cors = true;
```

Refer more :- http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/phonegap.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid your c# code will not be compatible with other platforms. You either need to write [Phonegap plugins](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html) for each platform or write JavaScript to check login.

Depending on your situation, Phonegap has APIs for accessing the device's filesystem or making use of browser storage (Web SQL database).

See the [Phonegap API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/index.html) for more info